# Fail to split a string in array by a character

Tags: php, string, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress website and I want to get some order details right after the submission. One of them, returned with a long string which I want to split and format it as I need. Here is the example:

```
echo $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();
My name<br />My address<br />My postcode
```

I try to split the string in the `<br />` to use each of the fields in a different place. I tried like this:

```
$data = explode("<br />", $order->get_formatted_shipping_address());
$name = $data[0];
$address = $data[1];
$post = $data[2];
```

However, the `<br />` keeps staying in the string and the `$name` has the whole string as in `$data`.

Any idea?

Comment: [Not able to generate the same.](https://3v4l.org/ApCsc)

Comment: what version of wordpress and woocommerce are you using?

Comment: @AlexAndrei WordPress 4.5.3, Woocommerce 2.5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the following on WooCommerce 2.6.1

```
$data = explode('<br/>',$order->get_formatted_shipping_address());
```

Note that the delimiter is `<br/>` and not as you used it `<br />`, yours has an extra space.

As an alternative, instead of `explode` you should use the [magic properties](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#magicProperties) from the class `WC_Abstract_Order`.

Example

```
print $order->shipping_first_name;
print $order->shipping_address_1;
print $order->shipping_postcode;
```

This will output the fields without going through the `implode` that happens inside `get_formatted_shipping_address()`

Comment: I used the second suggestion with the different functions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, I even tested it on my machine. Put this code in some new file and just test it to see if it gives the wanted result. If it does, then you're making a mistake on the place. Are you sure you are using the right variables?

```
<?php
    class wp {
        public function get_formatted_shipping_address() {
            return "My name<br />My address<br />My postcode";
        }
    }

    $order = new wp;

    $data = explode("<br />", $order->get_formatted_shipping_address());
    print_r($data);
    $name = $data[0];
    $address = $data[1];
    $post = $data[2];
```

Comment: Stupid mistake when I copy paste the code here and change some variable names to english. I use the actual `$data` variable for it. Sorry